# Return value from a thread

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a thread class below which reads a file from a url, then stores the result in a public static variable so it can be accessed from other classes. Is there a better to achieve this ?

Thanks

```
public class ReadContent implements Runnable{

    private HttpConnection connection;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private String url;

    public ReadContent(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        readContentURL();
    }

    private void readContentURL() {

        try {   
                connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();

            //  inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c ;
                while (true) {
                    c = inputStream.read();
                    if (c == -1)
                        break;
                    baos.write(c);
                }

                SavedJSON.result = new JSONObject(new String(baos.toByteArray()));

            } 
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }

}
```

Here is my proposed solution -

```
public class MyFuture{ 
      private final Object lock = new Object();

      private JSONObject value;
      public void set(JSONObject t){
          value = t;
          synchronized(lock){
              value = t;
              lock.notifyAll();  
          }
      }

      public JSONObject get(){
         synchronized(lock){
              while(value == null)
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              return value;
         }

      }    
    }

public class SavedJSON {

    public static MyFuture result;
    }

public class ReadContent implements Runnable{

    private HttpConnection connection;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private String url;

    public ReadContent(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        readContentURL();
    }

    private void readContentURL() {

        try {   
            int len = 0;
                connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            //  connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();

            //  inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c ;
                while (true) {
                    c = inputStream.read();
                    if (c == -1)
                        break;
                    ++len;
                    baos.write(c);
                }

                SavedJSON.result.set(new JSONObject(new String(baos.toByteArray(), 0, len, "utf-8")));

            } 
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }

}
```

Comment: SavedJSON.result is the static variable that the result is stored in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot use a Callable (and I am assuming you also cannot use a Future) you can try and create your own Future.  Its relatively simple:

```
public class MyFuture<T>{ // can you not use generics either?
  private final Object lock = new Object();

  private T value;
  public void set(T t){
      synchronized(lock){
          value = t;
          lock.notifyAll();  
      }
  }
  public T get(){
     synchronized(lock){
          while(value == null) lock.wait();

          return value;
     }

  }    
}
```

Now you can have `SavedJSON.result` be a `MyFuture` and whenever someone wants the value and needs to wait they can simply call `SavedJSON.result.get();` and the set can obviously be `SavedJSON.result.set(new JSONObject(new String(baos.toByteArray())));`

Edit:

This is to address your comment and edit.

First:  You may want to propagate the interrupted exception though.  Usually threads will try to 'stop' other threads with the use of interruption.  You can either add a throws declaration on the method, throw a runtime exception or simply return a null value.

Second:  You shouldnt have value = t outside of the synchronized block.  For various reasons this has potential to fail.  You should remove that line and it looks pretty good.

Comment: Pretty much this should get the job done. Just drop the generics since there are no generics for blackberry java apps. I use this approach all the time in my applications. Calling wait(),notifyAll() etc. is also a good idea but not always necessary.

Comment: THanks, ive tried above method, please see amended question. The variable does not seem to be set correctly ? Is my implementation correct ?

Comment: Seems there was an issue with initial methodology in that MyFuture is never actually initialised. I had add the following to SavedJson class  -public static MyFuture result = new MyFuture(); Thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `Callable` interface (for a `Runnable` which returns value) and the `Executors` class for a variety of different thread pool implementations.

Comment: I can't use Callable as this is for a BlackBerry device.

Answer (score 1):

For your case I propose to implement a callback, like this:

callback:

```
public interface SimpleCallback {
    public void onReceive(JSONObject data);
}
```

invoker:

```
...
SimpleCallback callback = new SimpleCallback() { 
    public void onReceive(JSONObject data) {
        // do something
    }
}
new Thread(new ReadContent(url, callback));
...
```

thread:

```
...
    // read input stream
    callback.onReceive(new JSONObject(new String(baos.toByteArray())));
} catch(Exception e){
...
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the concept of futures.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Answer (score 0):

Your result is not synchronized. You should improve your SavedJSON class in order to create getResult() and setResult() methods and make them syncronized. wait() and notify() methods also should help you.